# JTextArea string won't print to my console?

Tags: java, swing, methods, awt

I'm trying to make it so when I press a button what ever is in my JTextArea will be printed out via the System.out.print method, but something is quite not right. Here's my code:

```
public static void text(){
     JButton jb = new JButton("Button");
     final String s;
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     t1= new JTextArea(3,10);
     s=t1.getText();

     ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.print(s);
        }
     };

    jb.addActionListener(al);
    jp.add(jb);
    jp.add(t1);
    frame.add(jp);
    frame.setTitle("Card");  
    frame.setSize(700,500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

public static void main(String [ ] args){
    text();
}
```

Comment: We need to know the actual thing that "is not quite right".

Comment: The text in the JTextArea wouldn't print out to the console when I clicked on my button, but anyways someone already answer my question, thank anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `s=t1.getText()`, this does not mean that `s` always contains the text in `t1`. That means to set `s` to whatever text `t1` contains *right now* (i.e. when that line executes, which in your case is when setting up the GUI).

You probably want to get the text when the button is pressed:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // System.out.print(s); <- delete this
    System.out.print(t1.getText());
}
```

You can then also remove everything to do with `s`, since it's not used.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. By the way, you have any idea that I could Initialize a string to the text in the JTextArea and be able to use it like I wanted to? I'm still a little new to Java, thanks for your time.

Comment: @user4442652 use `t1.setText("hello world!");` or similar when you're setting up the GUI

Comment: I mean like String s = t1.getText( ); System.out.print( s ) ;  Something along those lines, like i wanted to do it originally, basically this was just a test program, my main goal was to be able to initialize the text inside the JTextArea to a String but it seems i failed, do you have any suggestions on how I can achieve this

Comment: @user4442652 What is "how I wanted to" then?